# Disable Java auto updater via policy/script or some other automated means

Tags: windows, group-policy, java

I started researching on this and it turned out that this was not as easy as it seemed it would be.

Basically looking to get some sort of automated way that I can turn off all the "an update is ready for your computer" messages that get thrown before the auto updating process takes place.

Any ideas?

It seems this gets complicated especially with Java because the versions change so fast.

Comment: You do realize that these are security updates? Failing to install them is asking for trouble.

Comment: You could do worse than investigate Ninite Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.  Best way depends on your client version, though, ultimately, you're just editing a registry value.

You're looking in `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\` for the `EnableJavaUpdate` key.  It's a `REG_DWORD`, and by default has a value of one.  Set the value to `00000000` (eight zeroes).

For XP, we put the below VBS script into a Startup Script and applied it to all our computers.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sRegKey = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy" 
oShell.RegWrite sRegKey & "\EnableJavaUpdate", 00000000, "REG_DWORD"
```

For Windows Vista and up, the easiest way is to use a Group Policy Preference or two (they can be temperamental with XP clients, so not recommended for use with XP).

For 32-bit/x86 Java running on a 32-bit version of Windows or 64-bit Java running on a 64-bit version of Windows, the registry value above is the one you need. [Here's a link to a guide for the process with pictures, and it includes instructions on setting up a GPP to do this](http://trekker.net/archives/how-do-i-disable-java-updates-with-group-policy/).

For 32-bit/x86 Java running on a 64-bit version of Windows, the key's in a different place, at `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy`.  Same value, though, and again, a value of 1 enables it, a value of 0 disables it. [Here's a link to a guide for the process with pictures, and it includes instructions on setting up a GPP to do this](http://trekker.net/archives/how-do-i-disable-32-bit-java-updates-on-64-bit-windows/).